# Draw only shadows on html5-canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to figure out how I can draw something on canvas and show only it's shadow, for example:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.shadowBlur=100;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 150;
ctx.shadowColor="red";
ctx.fillStyle="rgba(0,0,0,0.7)";
ctx.fillRect(20,20,100,80);
```

Here I draw a black rectangle and add a red shadow with an offset, I'd like to see only the shadow without the rectangle.

As you can see on the example, I tried using rgba color but when I set opacity it affects the shadow as well.

here is a fiddle for this code: http://jsfiddle.net/YYvFw/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

well the first thing that comes to mind is moving the rectangle out of the canvas and offsetting the shadow as far as you need it.

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    width = 100,
    height = 80,
    posX = 100,
    posY = 80;

    context.rect(-width, -height, width, height);
    context.shadowColor = 'red';
    context.shadowBlur = 40;
    context.shadowOffsetX = width+posX;
    context.shadowOffsetY = height+posY;
    context.fill();
```

that draws you the shadow at x:100 y:80

http://jsfiddle.net/S7WRx/2/

Comment: this was the first thing that came to my mind as well, but then i thought that i have multiple shapes and shadows, and the canvas is very large so there is no fix size that i can use to move it outside

Comment: you can always blur the whole canvas though. `#myCanvas {-webkit-filter: blur(5px);}` be a little more specific what exactly you need from that canvas.

Comment: how bluring the canvas helps me ? it will blur everything including the shadows...

Comment: i'm not a canvas nerd but for me it seems like thats just not going to happen. draw two shapes! one with alpha and another one outside of the canvas offsetting its shadow back inside.  you still haven't given us enough to provide you with actual code as an answer. so i'll just leave it as that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an easy way to do it. The only thing I could think of is to getImageData for the shadowed area, and then clear the canvas and paste that imageData onto it.

Comment: but what if the rectangle and the shadows overlap ?